# Adding a custom font to macOS app using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, fonts, info.plist, nsfont

I followed a bunch of tutorials but it doesn’t work: I simply want to add a custom font to a macOS app.

What I tried essentially:

1. **Added the `.ttf` font-files to my project**: Target Membership is set and I also made sure that the files are copied using `Copy Files` within `Bundle Phases`. After compiling I can see that all files are within the Bundle. So that seems to work perfectly fine.

[image]

2. `Info.plist`: I **added `Fonts provided by application`** and created an item for every font-file I want to add (values like `myFont.tff`).
3. I made sure that I use the **correct font name**. I installed the fonts on my system and configured a Label with Interface Builder so that it uses the desired font. I printed it’s value `print(myLabel.font.fontName)`.
4. Confusing: If the *exactly same* font-file I want to add to the app is installed in the systems Fontbook and activated, everything works well. When I deactivate it, it doesn’t work. For me that indicates that I am using the correct font name.
5. I found `ATSApplicationFontsPath` and tried to **add it to the `Info.plist`**, but neither using a path (recommended by the docs) or values like `.` (which seemed to work for some people out there) worked out.

[image]

Appreciate any help!

Comment: If you are thinking that you can use a custom font by just regestering it with Info.plist just as you do in iOS, no, that's how it works in Cocoa.

Comment: @ElTomato You don’t lead me into the right direction saying how it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved my problem by accident.

I noticed that within the Bundle files, my fonts were included twice: They were copied to the "Resources" directory as well as to the subpath I declared in the "Copy Files" Build Phases. 
I removed the fonts from my project, added them again (without checking the "Target Membership") and added them in the Build Phases so they were copied just to the subpath. After that it worked.

Additional notes:

Turned out that `Fonts provided by application` is a iOS only property so it is not needed for an macOS implementation.

Also, `ATSApplicationFontsPath` does not need any slashes. For example: `Fonts` should work just fine.

I had a difficult time finding the correct names for .ttf font files and sometimes discovered some strange behaviour: NSFont picked randomly fonts (regular, medium, bold...) from a font family without any code changes. By using .otf files instead I could solve that too.

Comment: Thanks man! Saved my day. I've been testing various solutions all day, but in the end, in my case, my app is multiplatform (iOS and macOS) and I had to add the fonts in the mac bundle, it does not work in the shared bundle.

Comment: thanks ixany! you have also saved my day but there is one problem that I am not able to access the added fonts in storyboard. Please help me out otherwise I need to set all fonts programmatic.

Answer (score 22):

I had a hard time getting this to work based on the previous answers, so I decided to write up an answer myself. This is based on previous answers by @ixany and @rob-keniger.

1. Create a folder named Fonts

[image]

2. Add fonts to the `Fonts` folder. Uncheck `Add to targets` and check `Copy items if needed`.

[image]

3. Add `Application fonts resource path` to Info.plist and enter `Fonts`.

[image]

4. Go to `Build Phases` and create a `New Copy Files Phase`.

[image]

5. Set the `Destinations` to `Resources` and `Subpath` to `Fonts`. Then add your font files to the list.

[image]

Comment: Works exactly like this. Thanks! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried doing it this way, The fonts didn't appear via either code or through a storyboard. Can you please assist

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me in Xcode 12 beta 1 running BigSur but these steps did.

1. Create a Fonts folder for organization.
2. Add your fonts to the project. Be sure to check the macOS target!
3. Set Application fonts resource path to "." (no quotes).

No need to edit build phases or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

THe value `ATSApplicationFontsPath` (i.e. `Application fonts resource path`) is relative to the `Resources` folder of your app bundle.

To see where your fonts are copied to:

1. In Xcode, expand the Products section under Project Navigator and click Show in Finder

[image: Locate app bundle]

2. In Finder, Ctrl-click on your app and click Show Resource Contents. Browse to the `Resources` folder and find your fonts there.
   [image]

Comment: I made sure every font file is copied to the Bundles directory. I tried `ATSApplicationFontsPath` leaving empty or with a value like `fonts/` but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Hard to see where things went wrong so I'm just giving some generic tips: (a) make sure your fonts are indeed copied to `Resources/fonts`; (b) try `fonts` instead of `fonts/` in the Info.plist file

Comment: (a) The files are copied correctly into `Contents/Resources/Fonts`, (b) Tried different ways but nothing seemed to work (`/Fonts`, `Fonts/`, `Fonts`)

Comment: Did you found solution? I'm also facing same issue taking lot of time.

Comment: Same issue here. I still can't get this to works. (I'm using the font from Storyboard.)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 12 to add custom fonts you have to exclude extension name from the string provided.

i.e.

.font(.custom("your font name", size:xx)) // works every time

.font(.custom("your font name.extension",size:xx)) // always fails

same is not true with Xcode 11.xx there fontname.extension is working.